# IS it okay to link to books you have to buy in an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just left an answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105136/how-to-implement-a-hook-views-pre-render-in-drupal-7/105143#105143) that suggest the use of a book that you should (although there are other ways to get a copy) buy.

Is it okay to point people to solutions that are commercial? Especially as I don't stand to benefit.

Comment: TL;DR: As an answer, no.  To support a good answer, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you should at least get the name of the book right, I'm sure Mr Tomlinson would be most perturbed ;)

But generally speaking: no, answers containing nothing (or little) more than a link are not considered answers on the Stack Exchange network.

The information that answers a question **needs to be here**, not on an external site (drupal.org being sort of an exception in a lot of cases), or in a book, otherwise the answer becomes useless when that site goes down/book goes out of print/etc.

Linking to the book itself, however, is not an issue, as long as the rest of the post actually answers the question directly.

Comment: Ok, thanks Clive. Should I remove my answer then? Is it too general? Should it be a comment on the answer you gave? However, I really did learn how to build modules and implement hooks from that book. I added 'Pro' to the title :)

Comment: @NectarSoft It is not "too general". Now it is not even an answer for anyone who don't have this book. And I think I'm a good proof one do not need to buy that book to "really get into developing custom modules", so it's not even that good of an advice - it may help some, but telling people "buy this if you want develop for Drupal" doesn't seem right.

Comment: Was only kidding - I'm doing some stuff for Apress at the moment so that book title pops up quite a lot :P A _comment_ pointing to the book would be infinitely more appropriate, yes - on the question itself or one of the answers, either is fine

Comment: Thanks, Clive, I moved the post. Makes sense. Molot, I am not sure I would read my comment the way you have, I  simply state that the book helped me, I didn't say it was imperative. However, maybe as I posted it as an answer, it would seem that I was saying that, which is why it is much more appropriate as a comment, as Clive pointed out.